# Can't get api request

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get data from this page:

https://api.statbank.dk/console#data

with

```
response_json = requests.get('https://api.statbank.dk/v1/data/mpk100/JSONSTAT?lang=en&valuePresentation=Value&timeOrder=Ascending&LAND=*&Tid=*')
```

print(response.content)

but I get the following error

```
b'{"errorTypeCode":"EXTRACT-NOTFOUND","message":"Kan ikke finde variablen: table"}'
```

Saying that it can't find the variable 'table'.

The table i'm trying to get is mpk100. But i dont see how to do it differently than what i've done.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing requests using pip.

```
pip install requests
```

Then try the following code.

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://api.statbank.dk/v1/data/mpk100/JSONSTAT?lang=en&valuePresentation=Value&timeOrder=Ascending&LAND=*&Tid=*')
print(response.content)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help alfie. I've done this already. This worked for me:
df=pd.read_json('https://api.statbank.dk/v1/data/mpk100/JSONSTAT?valuePresentation=Value&timeOrder=Ascending&LAND=*&Tid=*').reset_index()
df.head()
df

Comment: So the problem now is, how can i plot this correctly? I tried to put the x and y variables in, but i end up getting nothing with plotly and pandas

Answer (score 0):

Many statistical agencies ar using this special json-format [json-stat](https://json-stat.org). You should run: pip install [pyjstat](https://pypi.org/project/pyjstat/) for getting these data into a Pandas dataframe.